# How to assign array position to a variable for posterior use?

Tags: php

I got an array like this:

```
array(
   'name' => 'array1',
   'content' => array(
       'name' => 'array2',
       'content' => array(
           'name' => 'array3',
           'content' => array(...)
       )
   )
)
```

I want to insert data in the third array but don't wanna type something this length:

```
$array['content']['content']['content']... = 'something';
```

because I use it inside diferent `foreach` and it will become to long.

I try to assign the array into a variable like:

```
$array['content']['content']['content'] = array();
$content3 = $array['content']['content']['content'];
```

and then:

```
$content3['content4'] = 'something';
```

but doesn't store 'content4', any solution to this?

Comment: Sounds rather unpleasant :(

Comment: Array assignment always creates a copy; you're want to *assign by reference.*

Comment: Are you foreach'ing over this array or some other array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **&** to make content3 reference to $array['content']['content']['content']:

```
$array['content']['content']['content'] = array();
$content3 = &$array['content']['content']['content'];

$content3['content4'] = 'something';
```